# rails code works in console not in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've been looking for a few days not but just can't find what's going on. I've got code that when tested in the rails console works well, but in the controller it refuses to create the database entries.

The models that I use are:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :active_data_sets
  has_many :data_sets, :through => :active_data_sets  
end

class DataSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :project_id, :filename, :tempfilename

  has_many :active_data_sets
  has_many :projects, :through => :active_data_sets
end

class ActiveDataSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :data_set_id, :project_id

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :dataset  
end
```

I'm using a form_tag in my view because at a later stage I want to upload a file, which is not part of the model. I found out that the form_tag won't work at that point.
Calling url for the form is:

```
http://localhost:3000/data_sets/new?project_id=1
```

and the view:

```
<h1>DataSets#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/data_sets/new.html.erb</p>
<%= form_tag import_data_sets_path do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'project_id', params[:project_id] %>
    <p>
        dataset name:
        <%= text_field_tag :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= submit_tag "Create Dataset" %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

In the create method of the controller I have the following code

```
  def create
    @dataset = DataSet.new
    @dataset.active_data_sets.build(:project_id => params[:project_id].to_i)
    @dataset.name = params[:name]
    @dataset.save
  end
```

Which doesn't result in the entries being made in the database
When I enter the following code in the rails console I do endup with the correct entries in the database:

```
dataset = DataSet.new
dataset.active_data_sets.build(:project_id => 1)
dataset.name = 'name'
dataset.save
```

I thought that the hidden_field_tag returned all data as strings, which is why I added the .to_i, but that didn't seem to do the trick either.

Hopefully somebody sees the issue that I don't.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `build` does not save the object in the Database, use `create` instead: `@dataset.active_data_sets.create(:project_id => params[:project_id])`

Comment: what is `import_data_sets_path`? Are you sure that routes to the create action on your controller?

Comment: Do you have any validations on the dataset? Also, look in the params in the create method - what does that hash look like?

Comment: Thanks @gregates for pointing me in the right direction. Because I switched from form_for to form_tag i created a separate import route (with method), but all my code was still in the create method...